# How do I center flexbox child rows?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I have flexbox boxes with two rows inside (one for an icon, the other for a text).
I need to verticaly and horizontaly center my two rows (right now, only the 2nd is centered) inside my child box.. but can't manage to do it..

Here is my HTML template :

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let header of headers; let i = index;" size="6" (click)="openTimeline(header.ID)">
  <div class="row">
    <ion-icon name="{{icons[i]}}"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="rox">{{ header.title }}</div>
</ion-col>
```

My CSS one :

```
ion-col {
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  margin: 0.6vh 0;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo at : `<div class="rox">{{ header.title }}</div>` so the classes `row` doesn't apply to the second row. It should be `<div class="row">{{ header.title }}</div>`

Also our rows are displayed as column. If you display them as row, they will pile from top to bottom.
You also have to remove `width: 100%` on `.col` otherwise they will be to large to be side by side.

```
ion-col {
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  flex-direction: row; // element side by side
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  margin: 0.6vh 0;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex !important;
  // width: 100%; that's making one row taking all the space on the line
  height: 2em;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you ? Is it how you want to center your element ?